# How to undelete notes on iPhone "Notes" app?

Tags: ios, iphone, recovery, notes.app

iPhone has a default "Notes" app which allows us to store notes. Stored notes can be deleted by hitting the "Delete Note" button:

[image]

How do we recover a note that is accidentally deleted?

Is there anyway to undo the delete?

Comment: Ughhh - It's no answer, but [SimpleNote App](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/simplenote/id289429962?mt=8) has saved me many times and allowed the built in notes app to sit in an obscure folder. Perhaps iCloud will improve the notes app and change things, but for now notes can cause too much grief with a slip of the finger.

Comment: @bmike, Ok, I've just downloaded SimpleNote App. Darn Apple. I had this problem again, with a slip of hand there goes my 50 line note. With 122k views to this page, I wonder how many man-years of productivity has gone down the drain due to the existence of this app. Apple is being [as irresponsible as Microsoft](http://superuser.com/q/335321/78897) by releasing a built-in Text App that does not autobackup.

Comment: Wow. Old thread. Don't you sync your notes with iCloud now? I think Apple fixed that in iOS 4.0 - and iCloud web interface also has a "trash can" idiom to restore deleted documents so you don't need to keep losing your work :). Sorry it's still a problem for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an iTunes backup, you can browse it with [Doctor Telephone](https://www.doctor-telephone.com) and maybe [recover notes iphone](https://www.doctor-telephone.com/lost-notes/recover-deleted-note-on-iphone.html) again.

The linked app works only for Mac, but here's two alternatives (not tested) :

- [iPhone backup extractor](http://www.reincubate.com/labs/iphone-backup-extractor-how-extract-files-iphone-backup-windows/) which is a paid multiplatform app
- [iphonebackupbrowser](http://code.google.com/p/iphonebackupbrowser/) which is less polished and windows only, but free.

Comment: gosh by backup do you mean this: http://screenshoot.me/jiZAoc because i didn't have them synced Gosh

Comment: No, I meant the iPhone backup iTunes make before syncing.

Comment: Cool, look at my comment here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21426/how-do-i-use-the-iphone-ipod-touch-backup-extractor/21427#comment-24015

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to undo the delete.  You just have to shake your iphone, and this will activate the "undo" feature which seems to have been forgotten by most people (it was a feature of an iOS update a few revisions back around 2009).

In case you think I am kidding, [click here](http://www.knowyourmobile.com/appleiphone/iphonetips/typingtips/318625/shake_to_undo.html).

Comment: First thing I turn off when setting up a new iOS device

Comment: i meant i have deleted the entire note! not just a portion of the note. I've shaked it like mad but it's not responding. and i'm sure i'm shaking correctly because i've shaked it before last time

Comment: I think Pacerier is right...shake-to-undo primarily works for text editing and will not recover a dead note.

Comment: Sorry, from the way that Pacerier worded his post I thought he meant he had deleted some selected text. The only way he could recover a deleted note is to restore his iPhone from a previous backup (and that will only work if his note was already on his phone when he last did an iTunes sync).

Answer (score 6):

Apple solved this issue with an upgrade to iCloud and notes.app

There is now a deleted items folder that you can access on iOS within the notes app.

[image]

Just head to the **Recently Deleted** folder to recover your deleted work.

Answer (score 2):

If you sync your notes with Google, try looking for them in your Gmail's trash folder!