# How do I use the iPhone / iPod Touch Backup Extractor?

Tags: windows, backup

How do I use the iPhone / iPod Touch Backup Extractor?

http://supercrazyawesome.com/

I downloaded the file and extracted it but there isn't a single runnable file at all?

Does anyone know how do I start using it (get it running?).

Ps: I'm using Windows Vista, would this be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application you point out is a Mac only application. That's why it doesn't work on Windows Vista.

However, here's two alternatives :

- [iPhone backup extractor](http://www.reincubate.com/labs/iphone-backup-extractor-how-extract-files-iphone-backup-windows/) which is a paid multiplatform app
- [iphonebackupbrowser](http://code.google.com/p/iphonebackupbrowser/) which is less polished and windows only, but free.

You may as well be interested by [PhoneDisk](http://www.macroplant.com/phonedisk/) which allow to browse any connected iOS device without jailbreaking them. It does the job and works on Mac OS & Windows. It's a shareware, but the demo is fully usable.

Comment: I have a backup folder and all I want to do is to select and read all the notes within the backup folder. is that even possible? (phonedisk seems to read the files that are currently on the phone, which is not what I want.

Comment: This is possible. The first of my two links seems to make this easy. Have you tried it ? (in your case, PhoneDisk is useless)

Comment: i tried iphonebackupbrowser but it doesn't seem to do anything at all. take a look http://screenshoot.me/P91qgR

Comment: To recover your notes with the latter, you've to select "system". In system, you should see a sqlite database called `notes.sqlite` in `Library/Notes/`. It contains all your notes at the time of backup. You should open it with a software like [SQLite database browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html).

Comment: ok gosh it is showing me my current note: http://screenshoot.me/kcwNMe . do you know where do they store the  "past notes" ?

Comment: I don't think there's such things as "past notes", all my notes are in the `ZNOTEBODY` table. Are you sure you're looking at the content of the `ZNOTEBODY`table ? I'm afraid I can't help you further, sorry.