# How can I recover notes missing from the Notes app?

Tags: icloud, data-recovery, notes.app, ios

I recently opened the Notes app and found that about a month's worth of notes are missing.  There is a gap between August 5th and September 3rd.

(This time period includes a note I wrote while in an airport listing the names and desks of air staff I dealt with while trying to handle a canceled flight, and now I've failed a complaint with the airline and need those details.  A few hundred euros of compensation might ride on having these details.)

I found one question about [restoring deleted notes by using a program to read from the iTunes backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21359/how-to-undelete-notes-on-iphone-notes-app), but my iTunes only seems to keep one backup, the latest, and the notes are not present.  I synced before noticing, and of course iOS syncs over wifi now so it may have synced before then anyway.

- iPhone 4 running the latest iOS 5 (and latest iTunes etc. I am still using Lion.)
- The phone is synced with iCloud, which is also synced with my MBP and iPad.  I am signed into the same account on all of them.
- I do use GMail for email, but as far as I know not for notes.  I could not find my missing notes in any account.
- When I wrote the note, I had no data connection (overseas) but did a couple of days before and after
- I do not know when the notes vanished, but only noticed the hole in the dates when I looked for this specific important note.

What do I do?

Comment: Did you ever find these notes? Also, it is possible to sync your Notes with any IMAP account, which means it's technically possible you were syncing them to Gmail.

Comment: No, I never found them!  I searched GMail but didn't find them there, but I'll have another look.  I find the syncing a bit confusing really - it's not all working correctly, I'm not sure my calendars are syncing properly between devices right now either :/

Comment: does somebody has an update on this question - as it just happened to me. Also the 'on my computer' dissapears in the notes.app when activating the notes via iCloud. I am not able to find the note that dissappeared when writing it offline and connecting to the internet. Somehow there is nothning the icloud recovered items...

Comment: No update from me, sorry - I never recovered my missing notes :(

Answer (score 2):

This is a little like what happened to me, [I posted a question here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73962/icloud-seems-to-delete-notes-taken-on-my-mac-when-offline) relating to notes that had gone missing too.

It seems that if you take a note while offline, when you sync with icloud it will sometimes without warning delete notes it does not know about :( Luckily in my case since I had made the note on my mac it created a recovery folder for me.

Perhaps your phone may have done a similar thing? If you open notes and hit the 'accounts' button at the top, is there a 'recovered items' folder?