# iCloud seems to delete Notes taken on my Mac when offline

Tags: data-synchronization, icloud, backup, notes.app

I have just set up the Notes.app on my MBP (Running OSX 10.8.2) to link up with my iCloud account so that I could begin working with synchronised notes.

I make a lot of notes while I am out and about using my iPhone, so it seemed great to be able to have them all appear on my mac so that I can edit them or simply just to copy and paste into a document, or whatever I so please.

Due to my complete distrust of anything that is able to delete/merge/synchronise my data without me being entirely in control of the process, I do create a back up as I go along. I do this by having a backup folder under the 'On My Mac' header, and manually managing this.

Anyway, I was just in a seminar and using the Notes.app on my Mac to type out notes. My computer was not online at the time so the data was not immediately synced to my iPhone. When I got home (and therefore connected to the internet again on both mac and phone), I took a look at the notes app on my phone. No seminar notes. I then checked the notes app on my Mac - for fraction of a second I saw my seminar notes, before they for some bizarre reason deleted themselves. There goes four hours of work. And I hadn't backed it up.

Retrospectively, I should have worked in the 'On My Mac' folder and then transferred it to iCloud, but to be honest I didn't anticipate iCloud to be that dangerously careless when it comes to data!

**Has anyone else experienced this? Was the error caused on my behalf, and if so, is it preventable in the future?**

---

*Side note:*

Luckily I managed to get the notes back. I happened to created a new folder in the 'On my Mac' section, and upon doing so another folder appeared entitled 'Recovered Items'. In there were just over 120 copies of the note. Quite frankly that has left me even more confused and worried as to how the notes.app works. I really wanted to make use of this app because it seems like such a great idea, but on the other hand it seems so painfully broken and badly implemented that it is not worth the risk in doing so.

Comment: This has happened to me a couple of times as well, it's really quite annoying.

Comment: this just happened to me as well! Very frustrating. How did you create the 'On my Mac' folder? as it is not visible on my mac.

Comment: The old notes.app was notorious for pulling of s**t like this. Back then it used IMAP for sync. Atleast for the last year it has used iCloud for sync instead, and is finally stable.